# Swift: difference in the way to unwrapp an option variable

Tags: swift

Can some explain what is the difference between this two ways of unwrapping a variable:

version 1 :

```
let myVariable : String? = "my name"

let myNameVariable : String = myVariable!
```

version 2:

```
let myVariable : String? = "my name"

let myNameVariable : String! = myVariable
```

I'll really appreciate if some one explain the difference between those two ways of unwrapping a variable

Comment: If `myVariable` is `nil`, version 1 will crash when you force unwrap it with `myVariable!` and version 2 will crash when you try to use `myNameVariable`.

Answer (score 1):

About version 1

```
let myVariable : String? = "my name"

let myNameVariable : String = myVariable!
```

This is called unwrapping, unwrap from optional type.
So here type of myNameVariable is **String**

About version 2

```
let myVariable : String? = "my name"

let myNameVariable : String! = myVariable
```

I do not think this is unwrapping, it is about type conversion,
So here type of myNameVariable is **String!**

It is same as

```
 let myNameVariable = myVariable as String!
```

Update:
**Main difference**

Example 1

```
let myVariable : String? = "my name"

var myNameVariable = myVariable!

//myNameVariable = nil //Error

var implUnwrapVar:String! = myVariable

implUnwrapVar = nil//OK
```

Example 2

```
let myVariable : String? = nil

//var myNameVariable = myVariable! //error

var implUnwrapVar:String! = myVariable // ok
```

Comment: Per apple's documentation : let assumedString: String! = "An implicitly unwrapped optional string." . https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-XID_436 .

Comment: Implicitly unwrapped means you can use it as a unwrapped one.But,remind that,you should be careful,because if it is a `var`,it can be nil

Comment: In the first case how is called?

Comment: See the update code,I think that is the main difference.